# How to use querySelectorAll to disable a button if all radios in a div have not been checked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following page which I would like to force the user to check all the radios in the first view:

```js
function show(shown, hidden) {

  document.getElementById(shown).style.display = 'block';

  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';

  document.querySelector('[data-testid="crowd-submit"]').style.display = 'inline-block';
  return false;
}

function enableButton() {
  if (document.querySelectorAll("link[type^=radio]:checked") !== null) {
    document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```css
[data-testid="crowd-submit"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>

<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">


  <!-- Start Page number one (part 1) -->
  <div id="Page1">
    <h2>Part 1/2</h2>

    <div class="container">
      <h4> this is question 1?</h4>
      <input type="radio" value="val1" name="question1_1" required onclick="enableButton()">A</input>
      <input type="radio" value="val2" name="question1_1" required onclick="enableButton()">B</input>
      <input type="radio" value="val3" name="question1_1" required onclick="enableButton()">C</input>
      <i></i>
    </div>



    <div class="container">
      <h4> this is question 2?</h4>
      <input type="radio" value="val1" name="question2_2" required onclick="enableButton()">A</input>
      <input type="radio" value="val2" name="question2_2" required onclick="enableButton()">B</input>
      <input type="radio" value="val3" name="question2_2" required onclick="enableButton()">C</input>
      <i></i>
    </div>



    <button type="button" id="button" class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto" disabled onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');"><b>Next</b></button>

    <br>
    <br>

  </div>
  <!-- End Page number one (part 1) -->

  <!-- start Page number two (part 2) -->
  <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
    <h2>Part 2/2</h2>


    <div class="container">
      <h4> this is question 2?</h4>
      <input type="radio" value="val1" name="question3_3" required onclick="enableButton()">A</input>
      <input type="radio" value="val2" name="question3_3" required onclick="enableButton()">B</input>
      <input type="radio" value="val3" name="question3_3" required onclick="enableButton()">C</input>
      <i></i>
    </div>




  </div>
</crowd-form>
```

How can I disable the next button, until all the radios in the first view have not been answered?

**So far, what I tried was:**

```
document.querySelectorAll("link[type^=radio]:checked") !== null
```

And

```
if (document.querySelectorAll("link[type^=radio]:checked").length !== null) {
document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
    }


  }
```

And with Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
        $("input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

However, these attemps have not worked, because if you answer only one set of radios in the first view, the website allows you to continue with the second one. How can I disable the next button, until all the checkboxes in the first view have been completed?

Comment: use document.querySelectorAll("link[type^=radio]:checked").length

Comment: @ZiaAhmad still the same, is not working because if you can go to the next view even if you only answered one question

Comment: if (document.querySelectorAll("link[type^=radio]:checked").length < document.querySelectorAll("link[type^=radio]").length) {
    document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
  }

Something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is even `link` in `link[type^=radio]`?
its `input[type^=radio]`

Also if you are checking `.length` you need to compare it to an number not `null`...

`.length` Always returns an number, `0 >`

```
.length !== 0
```

```js
function show(shown, hidden) {

  document.getElementById(shown).style.display = 'block';

  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';

  document.querySelector('[data-testid="crowd-submit"]').style.display = 'inline-block';
  return false;
}

function enableButton() {
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("input[type^=radio][name=question1_1]:checked").length)
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("input[type^=radio][name=question1_2]:checked").length)

  if (document.querySelectorAll("input[type^=radio][name=question1_1]:checked").length !== 0 && document.querySelectorAll("input[type^=radio][name=question2_2]:checked").length !== 0) {
    document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```css
[data-testid="crowd-submit"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>

<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">


  <!-- Start Page number one (part 1) -->
  <div id="Page1">
    <h2>Part 1/2</h2>

    <div class="container">
      <h4> this is question 1?</h4>
      <input type="radio" value="val1" name="question1_1" required onclick="enableButton()">A</input>
      <input type="radio" value="val2" name="question1_1" required onclick="enableButton()">B</input>
      <input type="radio" value="val3" name="question1_1" required onclick="enableButton()">C</input>
      <i></i>
    </div>



    <div class="container">
      <h4> this is question 2?</h4>
      <input type="radio" value="val1" name="question2_2" required onclick="enableButton()">A</input>
      <input type="radio" value="val2" name="question2_2" required onclick="enableButton()">B</input>
      <input type="radio" value="val3" name="question2_2" required onclick="enableButton()">C</input>
      <i></i>
    </div>



    <button type="button" id="button" class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto" disabled onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');"><b>Next</b></button>

    <br>
    <br>

  </div>
  <!-- End Page number one (part 1) -->

  <!-- start Page number two (part 2) -->
  <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
    <h2>Part 2/2</h2>


    <div class="container">
      <h4> this is question 2?</h4>
      <input type="radio" value="val1" name="question3_3" required onclick="enableButton()">A</input>
      <input type="radio" value="val2" name="question3_3" required onclick="enableButton()">B</input>
      <input type="radio" value="val3" name="question3_3" required onclick="enableButton()">C</input>
      <i></i>
    </div>




  </div>
</crowd-form>
```

If you want to use 0 as compression just use more direct CSS targeting and add one more condition:

```
if (document.querySelectorAll("input[type^=radio][name=question1_1]:checked").length !== 0 && document.querySelectorAll("input[type^=radio][name=question2_2]:checked").length !== 0)
```

so you can put in those two groups any number of options, and in each at least one needs to be picked.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, if you answer only question one, and ignore question 2 you are allowed to continue, I would like to avoid this behavior. All the radios must be answered in the first view before going to the next view

Comment: @aywoki Oh my my, just change number to 2? `=== 2` That will make sure 2 radios are cheeked in set of two.

Comment: Is there any way of getting that number without hard coding it?

Comment: @aywoki Yes,  just count number of radio elements in one grupe and compare that  number with  with number of cheeked ones. Ill edit the fiddle now...

Comment: @aywoki You can find the number by using `document.querySelectorAll(".container").length`.

Comment: @JustARandomGuyOnTheInternet In a single div? or in all the document? I end up doing that trick because the template doesnt allow me to have more than one page

Comment: @aywoki You can find the number of questions on only one page by `document.querySelectorAll("#PageN .container").length` where `PageN` is the id of the page.

Comment: @aywoki edited with one more way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the number of radio buttons that are checked, right now you are just checking if any radio buttons are checked.

```
function enableButton() {
  // check if both radio buttons are checked
  if (document.querySelectorAll("link[type^=radio]:checked").length == 2) {
    document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried this, however, now I cant go to the next view (div)

Comment: @aywoki Can you show us the code where you called `enableButton()`?

Comment: Thanks again, in the code I call it in `required onclick="enableButton()`

Comment: @aywoki When you say you can't go to the next view, do you mean that the button stays disabled when you check 2 radio buttons?